# Filter Duplicate Messages IoT Device

Tags: c#, filter, async-await, message, azure-iot-hub

I am working on a console application program that receives messages from an Azure IoT Device and is using a timer to receive the messages every two seconds.  Upon receiving a message the device sends out a call to complete it.  The issue that I am experiencing is that the message does not complete in Azure before the device receives it again, which results in the message getting reprocessed.  I have tried to filter incoming messages when it is the same message coming in multiple times, but the messages are coming in with the same message id whether or not they are duplicate messages or new messages.  I do not have access to control the incoming message's message id field and make it unique, but that would solve the problem.  The sequence number is unique for every message that comes in whether it is duplicate or not so I cannot use that as a filter either.  Is there a way to filter a message to see if it is a duplicate without the message id field?

```
//Within Program.cs > Main():

_timer = new Timer(Operations, null, 0, _timerInterval); //_timerInterval is set to 2000


//Within Initialize class used to setup device client:

//Fully qualified namespace for DeviceClient:
//Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient

string connectionString = "code removed for example";

var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);


//Within Operations class:

var message = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();

if (message != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message?.MessageId))
{
    //Filtering message based on MessageId
    if (_memoryCache.Get(message.MessageId) == null)
    {
        _memoryCache.Set(message.MessageId, message.MessageId, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10));

        await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(message);

        //Processing message
        await ProcessMessage(message);
    }
    else
    {
        await deviceClient.RejectAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify, is this IoT device something you have developed, or an off-the-shelf product? The IoT device that should be responsible for explicitly setting a unique id on each message so you can handle scenarios like this. Have you put a breakpoint and looked at all the properties provided at runtime? It may be provided in the `message.Properties` dictionary with a custom name

Comment: Hi Andrew, this is a Microsoft Azure IoT Hub Device.  It looks like the message id can be set, but since the message does not originate from this program I cannot set it here and make it unique.  I have set a break point and have tried to filter on any of the built-in message properties as well as the Message.Properties dictionary, but there is nothing that can serve as a unique identifier in either of those places.

Comment: @Developer what do you consider a duplicate message? How do you know a message is a duplicate?

Comment: A duplicate message is one that has the same message id, properties and content as another.  The issue that I am running into is that different messages (not duplicates) can have the same content, properties and message ids as others, thereby eliminating anything that would render them unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message` package to retrieve the Device client message values.

Use the IOT explicit unique id in message to check the duplicates while receiving.

Follow the below code to check the duplicate value

```
List<string> FinalResponse = new List<string>();

Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message Response = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
if (Response == null)
{
    await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
    continue;
}

 //here you can use the explicit properties like message id or correlation Id 
Trace.WriteLine(Response.MessageId.ToString());
await this.deviceClient.CompleteAsync(Response);
var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Response.GetBytes());
FinalResponse.Add(content);
```

Either you can use above one or use below conditions

Create a `List` and **ADD** all values to the list which get from Device

Add condition to **ignore** If any **duplicates** occur while insert into list.

Then send unduplicated values to Azure.